# Find the length of the main diagonal of a parallelepiped

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given vectors $x = (0,3,0)$, $y = (2, 2, 0)$ and $z = (1, 1, 3)$. These three vectors with their tails at the origin represent the piped.

I know I need to use orthogonal projection, but I am not sure in what "order" to do so.

I tried:

$$((0,3,0) - (2,2,0) * (1,1,3)) / ||(1,1,3)$$

After solving this out, I get $-1/\sqrt{11}$

This seems a little bit too simple, as all I did was plug the given vectors into the formula, in the order they were given. I would like to know if I am on the right track, and if so, what I need to change to put the vectors into a form in which I can then plug into the equation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are four diagonals of a parallelepiped, namely, the line segments connecting opposite vertices. In your case, the $8$ vertices are $\varepsilon_1x+\varepsilon_2y+\varepsilon_3z$
where $\varepsilon_i=\pm 1$  for $i=1,2,3$. I suppose that "main diagonal" refers to the longest diagonal. So let's look at all four diagonals:

The pairs of opposite vertices are:

$v_1=x+y+z$ and $-v_1$, that is: $(3,6,3)$ and $(-3,-6,-3)$.

$v_2=-x+y+z$ and $-v_2$, that is: $(3,0,3)$ and $(-3,0,-3)$.

$v_3=x-y+z$ and $-v_3$, that is: $(-1,2,3)$ and $(1,-2,-3)$.

$v_4=x+y-z$ and $-v_4$, that is: $(1,4,-3)$ and $(-1,-4,3)$.

and the corresponding lengths of the corresponding diagonals are:

$d_1=||2v_1||=6\sqrt{6}$

$d_2=||2v_2||=6\sqrt{2}$

$d_3=||2v_3||=2\sqrt{14}$

$d_4=||2v_4||=2\sqrt{26}$

Of these, the longest one is $6\sqrt{6}$, so this would be the length of the main diagonal.

Comment: The question says, "find the length of the main diagonal (from the origin to its opposite vertex"